# How to match multiple items from a list with one element from another list?

Tags: python, list, date, plot, items

I need to match items from the list `array` (364 items) with the list `months` (12 items). There will be multiple items from `array` that correspond to each month in `months`.

```
array = ['309', '307', '303', '296', '322', '340', '321', '314', '327', '315', '316', '333', '296', '286', '289', '290', '316', '317', '333', '348', '398', '396', '404', '424', '402', '357', '320', '315', '321', '328', '312', '293', '302', '296', '286', '281', '281', '  0', '312', '326', '332', '293', '242', '259', '268', '316', '296', '303', '280', '308', '314', '298', '307', '303', '300', '284', '289', '337', '308', '300', '288', '333', '321', '373', '301', '272', '288', '322', '318', '314', '321', '297', '299', '306', '312', '325', '334', '390', '339', '317', '343', '336', '357', '366', '383', '379', '355', '342', '369', '362', '359', '360', '380', '388', '393', '362', '347', '335', '322', '334', '313', '309', '303', '304', '326', '354', '364', '360', '343', '335', '343', '366', '318', '347', '326', '327', '329', '334', '347', '364', '346', '338', '337', '325', '304', '285', '298', '310', '316', '311', '321', '323', '360', '351', '337', '345', '372', '367', '356', '331', '308', '323', '327', '312', '300', '296', '305', '323', '338', '328', '319', '315', '315', '313', '316', '314', '312', '354', '317', '323', '324', '352', '360', '342', '333', '348', '335', '320', '321', '326', '327', '323', '303', '318', '308', '307', '302', '293', '304', '322', '302', '307', '304', '302', '287', '290', '306', '299', '297', '284', '289', '287', '316', '292', '291', '307', '300', '318', '302', '309', '320', '296', '293', '291', '287', '293', '287', '296', '293', '297', '287', '296', '296', '290', '287', '290', '290', '302', '298', '301', '297', '302', '290', '297', '288', '288', '299', '319', '311', '300', '302', '305', '294', '293', '288', '288', '289', '291', '286', '282', '280', '287', '279', '294', '345', '344', '292', '317', '296', '287', '288', '285', '291', '300', '298', '288', '288', '287', '275', '282', '288', '270', '272', '283', '284', '284', '295', '290', '279', '290', '287', '276', '289', '286', '295', '301', '287', '332', '305', '304', '275', '263', '266', '256', '257', '269', '258', '257', '273', '291', '277', '272', '280', '266', '269', '256', '282', '274', '308', '295', '288', '331', '290', '295', '283', '288', '285', '267', '274', '279', '300', '290', '293', '308', '285', '288', '279', '270', '281', '297', '296', '275', '255', '242', '239', '242', '269', '275', '278', '286', '276', '269', '283', '290', '317', '286', '287', '282', '273', '289', '322', '352', '268', '290', '311', '277', '256', '246', '255', '252', '265', '269', '265', '278', '272', '273', '302', '287', '284', '316', '318', '310', '280', '288', '293', '291'] 

months=['January 2020', 'February 2020', 'March 2020', 'April 2020', 'May 2020', 'June 2020', 'July 2020', 'August 2020', 'September 2020', 'October 2020', 'November 2020', 'December 2020']
```

The 364 values in `array` correspond to the ozone data of each day from the last year 2020, therefore I need to match each 31 (or 30, even 29 in the case of February and December) items to the right month, considering that the first value in 'array' corresponds with the date 01-01-2020 and the last value corresponds with the 29-12-2020. I don't really know if there is a command or if I directly have to do it with code.

My final goal of the code is to plot, `months` on the x axis and `array` on the y axis, with any libraries like matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plot(months, array)
plt.ylabel('Ozone Madrid') 
plt.xlabel('Months') 
plt.show()
```

Currently I cannot plot this because the arguments (the two lists) that take `plt.plot()` don't have the same number of items. That's why I thought on this previous step.

Are there any other ways to do this faster and more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the day's month based on its position in the year:

```
from datetime import date
def get_month_from_yday(year, yday):
    '''
        year is the reference year
        yday is the day's position in the year (0 is January 1st etc.)
    '''
    return date.fromordinal(date(year,1,1).toordinal() + yday).strftime("%B %Y")
```

**Input**

```
# Month if the 1st day of the year
print(get_month_from_yday(2020, 0))

# Month if the 32nd day of the year
print(get_month_from_yday(2020, 31))

# Month if the 361st day of the year
print(get_month_from_yday(2020, 360))
```

**Output**

```
January 2020
February 2020
December 2020
```

With this function you could get the day's month based on your array's index.

**Displaying graph**

In order to distinguish each month on the graph, I drew rectangles of different colors for each month.
I also played around to show a tick on the x-axis at the beginning of each month.

```
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def get_month_from_yday(year, yday):
    '''
        year is the reference year
        yday is the day's position in the year (0 is January 1st etc.)
    '''
    return date.fromordinal(date(year,1,1).toordinal() + yday).strftime("%B %Y")

# Input value
array = ['309', '307', '303', '296', '322', '340', '321', '314', '327', '315', '316', '333', '296', '286', '289', '290', '316', '317', '333', '348', '398', '396', '404', '424', '402', '357', '320', '315', '321', '328', '312', '293', '302', '296', '286', '281', '281', '  0', '312', '326', '332', '293', '242', '259', '268', '316', '296', '303', '280', '308', '314', '298', '307', '303', '300', '284', '289', '337', '308', '300', '288', '333', '321', '373', '301', '272', '288', '322', '318', '314', '321', '297', '299', '306', '312', '325', '334', '390', '339', '317', '343', '336', '357', '366', '383', '379', '355', '342', '369', '362', '359', '360', '380', '388', '393', '362', '347', '335', '322', '334', '313', '309', '303', '304', '326', '354', '364', '360', '343', '335', '343', '366', '318', '347', '326', '327', '329', '334', '347', '364', '346', '338', '337', '325', '304', '285', '298', '310', '316', '311', '321', '323', '360', '351', '337', '345', '372', '367', '356', '331', '308', '323', '327', '312', '300', '296', '305', '323', '338', '328', '319', '315', '315', '313', '316', '314', '312', '354', '317', '323', '324', '352', '360', '342', '333', '348', '335', '320', '321', '326', '327', '323', '303', '318', '308', '307', '302', '293', '304', '322', '302', '307', '304', '302', '287', '290', '306', '299', '297', '284', '289', '287', '316', '292', '291', '307', '300', '318', '302', '309', '320', '296', '293', '291', '287', '293', '287', '296', '293', '297', '287', '296', '296', '290', '287', '290', '290', '302', '298', '301', '297', '302', '290', '297', '288', '288', '299', '319', '311', '300', '302', '305', '294', '293', '288', '288', '289', '291', '286', '282', '280', '287', '279', '294', '345', '344', '292', '317', '296', '287', '288', '285', '291', '300', '298', '288', '288', '287', '275', '282', '288', '270', '272', '283', '284', '284', '295', '290', '279', '290', '287', '276', '289', '286', '295', '301', '287', '332', '305', '304', '275', '263', '266', '256', '257', '269', '258', '257', '273', '291', '277', '272', '280', '266', '269', '256', '282', '274', '308', '295', '288', '331', '290', '295', '283', '288', '285', '267', '274', '279', '300', '290', '293', '308', '285', '288', '279', '270', '281', '297', '296', '275', '255', '242', '239', '242', '269', '275', '278', '286', '276', '269', '283', '290', '317', '286', '287', '282', '273', '289', '322', '352', '268', '290', '311', '277', '256', '246', '255', '252', '265', '269', '265', '278', '272', '273', '302', '287', '284', '316', '318', '310', '280', '288', '293', '291'] 
months=['January 2020', 'February 2020', 'March 2020', 'April 2020', 'May 2020', 'June 2020', 'July 2020', 'August 2020', 'September 2020', 'October 2020', 'November 2020', 'December 2020'] 

# List of months for each of the array values
data_month = [get_month_from_yday(2020, i) for i in range(len(array))]
# List of array values as integer
y_values = [int(x) for x in array]

# List containing the index of the months starts
month_starts_index = [i for i in range(len(data_month)) if i==0 or (i!=0 and data_month[i-1] != data_month[i]) or i == len(data_month)-1]

# Draw a vertical span of different color for each month
colors=['red','blue']
for i in range(len(month_starts_index)):
    if i!=0:
        ax.axvspan(month_starts_index[i-1], month_starts_index[i], color=colors[i%len(colors)], alpha=0.3)

# Display a tick on the x-axis at each month start
plt.xticks(month_starts_index, [month for i, month in enumerate(data_month) if i in month_starts_index], rotation=45)

plt.xlabel('Months') 
plt.ylabel('Ozone Madrid')
plt.xlim(0, len(y_values)-1)
plt.plot(range(len(y_values)), y_values)
plt.show()
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond Marc, about your code, I still don't understand how can I use it for my problem... How can I use 'datetime' commands if they take dates (not array's index) as arguments?... Am I wrong?

Comment: You're very welcome. I edited my answer to give an example of how you can plot the values grouped by month.

Comment: Thank you again, that was really helpfull!! I was coding it right now and then I saw your respond, you saved me some time... Just one last question, how could I plot the same results with a linear graphic instead of the columns??? I still need to check better the matplotlib documentation to learn better the command-lines, so if you know it I'll be forever grateful (as you can see, I'm a very beginner)

Comment: You're very welcome :) 
I'm not sure about what the way you want to plot the data though. If you want to plot a classic line graph why do you need to group the data by month?

Comment: I need the linear graph to show the ozone time-dependent evolution (I have daily values but I cannot plot it with days on the x-axis because there are too many of them). The next step is to change it to the frequency-dependent by using the Fourier transform. Having both in the linear format will help me to study and compare better the results of the ozone evolution among several graphics. Anyway I think is solved, I've just posted the answer so anyone can read it. Still: thanks a lot for your help Marc :)

Comment: Hi @Azar_y_Kaos I saw you got a solution below which works very well, I didn't know Panda allowed to do that (btw I really recommend you check that library out, it's extremely useful if you're doing data analysis).
I edited my comment above with another solution in case you're interested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `monthrange` function from `calendar` (built in) to get the number of days of a month. Your code would be something like this

```
from calendar import monthrange

month_vals = []

for i in range(1, 13):
    vals = array[:monthrange(2020, i)[1]]
    array = array[monthrange(2020, i)[1]:]
    month_vals.append(vals)
```

**NOTE**: Your `array` has 366 values not 364

Comment: My mistake, thank you for notice it! I didn't check it before posting... that's because after I copied the list here I edited the file from which I get the ozone data (actually I've just deleted 2 files which corresponded with the 2 extra items that I finally posted). An about the code, I'll try to use 'monthrange' but I don't need to do the average value of each month, I need all these values, but grouped in months in order to plot them

Comment: In that case, I'll update the answer. But I don't think `plt.plot(months, array)` will plot it just the way you want to. You might need to look a bit more into `matplotlib` to do that

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so another guy in the spanish Stack Overflow's (all the credits to the user: **Rubiales Alberto**) post gave me the key so I post it here if it's helpfull for someone else.

Although I still need to have the same number of arguments in both `months`, and `array in order to plot it, we can create the months list by using` pandas` library. Here is the code:

**Input**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = ['309', '307', '303', '296', '322', '340', '321', '314', '327', '315', '316', '333', '296', '286', '289', '290', '316', '317', '333', '348', '398', '396', '404', '424', '402', '357', '320', '315', '321', '328', '312', '293', '302', '296', '286', '281', '281', '  0', '312', '326', '332', '293', '242', '259', '268', '316', '296', '303', '280', '308', '314', '298', '307', '303', '300', '284', '289', '337', '308', '300', '288', '333', '321', '373', '301', '272', '288', '322', '318', '314', '321', '297', '299', '306', '312', '325', '334', '390', '339', '317', '343', '336', '357', '366', '383', '379', '355', '342', '369', '362', '359', '360', '380', '388', '393', '362', '347', '335', '322', '334', '313', '309', '303', '304', '326', '354', '364', '360', '343', '335', '343', '366', '318', '347', '326', '327', '329', '334', '347', '364', '346', '338', '337', '325', '304', '285', '298', '310', '316', '311', '321', '323', '360', '351', '337', '345', '372', '367', '356', '331', '308', '323', '327', '312', '300', '296', '305', '323', '338', '328', '319', '315', '315', '313', '316', '314', '312', '354', '317', '323', '324', '352', '360', '342', '333', '348', '335', '320', '321', '326', '327', '323', '303', '318', '308', '307', '302', '293', '304', '322', '302', '307', '304', '302', '287', '290', '306', '299', '297', '284', '289', '287', '316', '292', '291', '307', '300', '318', '302', '309', '320', '296', '293', '291', '287', '293', '287', '296', '293', '297', '287', '296', '296', '290', '287', '290', '290', '302', '298', '301', '297', '302', '290', '297', '288', '288', '299', '319', '311', '300', '302', '305', '294', '293', '288', '288', '289', '291', '286', '282', '280', '287', '279', '294', '345', '344', '292', '317', '296', '287', '288', '285', '291', '300', '298', '288', '288', '287', '275', '282', '288', '270', '272', '283', '284', '284', '295', '290', '279', '290', '287', '276', '289', '286', '295', '301', '287', '332', '305', '304', '275', '263', '266', '256', '257', '269', '258', '257', '273', '291', '277', '272', '280', '266', '269', '256', '282', '274', '308', '295', '288', '331', '290', '295', '283', '288', '285', '267', '274', '279', '300', '290', '293', '308', '285', '288', '279', '270', '281', '297', '296', '275', '255', '242', '239', '242', '269', '275', '278', '286', '276', '269', '283', '290', '317', '286', '287', '282', '273', '289', '322', '352', '268', '290', '311', '277', '256', '246', '255', '252', '265', '269', '265', '278', '272', '273', '302', '287', '284', '316', '318', '310', '280', '288', '293', '291']

#The numbers of the list are string type, so we transform them into integers:
array = [int(n) for n in array]

#We create a list of months, this is the important command-line:
months = pd.date_range("01-01-2020", "31-12-2020")


plt.plot(months, array)
plt.ylabel('Ozone Madrid')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.show()
```

**Output**

```
# (It doesn't allow me to upload images yet cause I'm a beginner here, 
# but it gives me the linear graph that I needed)
```

Anyway I'm not really sure why using `pd.date_range("date1", "date2")` from `pandas` library to plot, adjust automaticly the data to this kind of graph instead of the other options that the people posted me here, but since `pandas` was coded to data analysis, the next thing I'll do is to read its documentation.

Thanks a lot for your help